# web3 - Error when calling sendTransaction with @truffle/contract on Ropsten Infura

Tags: web3js, truffle, nodejs, infura

My smart contract is already deployed on Ropsten TestNet provided by Infura at `0x63865E0F065C7b865e1a2EE4d99C383A414Bec22` address.
I want to sendTransaction using NodeJS(v.10.16.1) + Web3(v.1.2.6) + [@truffle/contract](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract)(v.4.1.11). This is my NodeJS code -

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var Web3            = require('web3');
var contract        = require("@truffle/contract");
var path            = require('path');
var MyContractJSON  = require(path.join(__dirname, 'build/contracts/contract.json'));

var provider    = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/PROJECT_ID");

var MyContract = contract(MyContractJSON);
MyContract.setProvider(provider);
const contract_address = "0x63865E0F065C7b865e1a2EE4d99C383A414Bec22";


app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var newUser = req.body.username;
    var account = req.body.account;
    req.session.currentUser = account;

    MyContract.at(contract_address).then(function(instance) {

        return instance.registerUser.sendTransaction(newUser, {from: account});

    }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        res.render("dashboard", {name: newUser, account: account});

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
```

I am getting this **ERROR** on `sendTransaction` -

```
Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available\n    at Object.ErrorResponse (...\\node_modules\\web3-core-helpers\\src\\errors.js:29:16)\n    at ...\\node_modules\\web3-core-requestmanager\\src\\index.js:140:36\n    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (...\\node_modules\\web3\\node_modules\\web3-providers-http\\src\\index.js:110:13)\n    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (...\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)\n    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState ...\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request.js:208:14)\n    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (...\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request.js:318:14)\n    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (...\\node_modules\\xhr2-cookies\\dist\\xml-http-request.js:289:61)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)\n    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)'
```

I am using **Metamask**(v.7.7.8) and managing the account address via `express-session`. I know that **Infura** does not support `sendTransaction` but **@truffle/contract** does not support `sendRawTransaction` too. 
Please help me find an easier solution with @truffle/contract.

Comment: Why `@truffle/contract` and not `web3.eth.Contract`?

Comment: Also, since we don't have the file `build/contracts/contract.json` from your local machine, and you haven't verified your contract on Etherscan, please post the ABI (or by the least, the declaration of function `registerUser, so that we can use it in order to create that ABI ourselves).

Comment: `@truffle/contract` handles contract abstraction in a better way. It handles the gas values and from addresses by default which we need to manage in `web3.eth.Contract`.

Comment: Please post the ABI, or by the least, the declaration of function `registerUser`, so that we can use it in order to create that ABI ourselves. **We don't have your build/contracts/contract.json file**!

Comment: This is the contract 
 - https://gist.github.com/surhud004/20c92666c35a373b7afef960374d8766

Comment: ABI Please......

Comment: Yes I have updated it in the same gist.

Comment: There is no function `registerUser(string)` in [your bytecode](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x63865E0F065C7b865e1a2EE4d99C383A414Bec22#code). How do I know? Because I printed the function hash - `Web3.utils.keccak256("registerUser(string)")`, and I couldn't find the first 4 bytes (8 hexadecimal characters) of the printout (704f1b94) in your bytecode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105591/discussion-between-surhud004-and-goodvibration).

Comment: Please make sure you've deployed it correctly (or alternatively, verify it on Etherscan in order to convince us that the function is indeed there).

Comment: New contract address -  `0x48d337bB8211fF08a95d1Fe8D40d403aAC141a26` I have created another contract again.

Comment: This is exactly the same contract (same bytecode). Perhaps you haven't compiled it properly or something. As I mentioned above, I am not convinced that this contract implements this function, because I cannot see the first 8 digits of `Web3.utils.keccak256("registerUser(string)")` in it. Please verify the contract on etherscan, so we can all be convinced that it implements this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created and compiled a contract according to [the one that you've posted in a comment](https://gist.github.com/surhud004/20c92666c35a373b7afef960374d8766).

I have deployed it to Ropsten, and then verified it on Etherscan.

As you can see on [Etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x6285f7cc0cd9d4e5dbb81353276dcc099fa9c6b9#code), its byte-code contains the sequence `704f1b94`, which is the function-selector of function `registerUser(string)`.

And as you can see on [Etherscan](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x63865E0F065C7b865e1a2EE4d99C383A414Bec22#code), the byte-code of your contract **does not** contain this function-selector, which means that your contract **does not** implement this function!

This by itself is a good enough reason for your transaction to revert.

**A few technical notes:**

1. You can generate the [function-selector](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html#function-selector) above by taking the first 4 bytes (8 hexadecimal characters) of the printout of `console.log(Web3.utils.keccak256("registerUser(string)"));`.
2. Here is the contract which I have compiled, deployed and verified on Etherscan:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.26;

contract MyContract {

    struct user {
        address id;
        string name;
    }

    uint internal totalUsers = 0;
    mapping(address => user) internal users;

    function registerUser(string memory name) public {
        user storage u = users[msg.sender];
        require(keccak256(abi.encodePacked((name))) != keccak256(abi.encodePacked((""))));
        if(msg.sender == u.id) {
            revert("already registered");
        } else {
            users[msg.sender] = user(msg.sender, name);
            totalUsers++;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Here is the NodeJS script which I have used for testing the contract function:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const PROJECT_ID  = process.argv[2];
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.argv[3];

const ABI  = [{"type":"function","name":"registerUser","inputs":[{"name":"name","type":"string","internalType":"string"}],"outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","constant":false,"payable":false}];
const ADDR = "0x6285F7CC0cD9D4E5DBB81353276DCc099fa9C6B9";

async function send(web3, account, transaction, value = 0) {
    const options = {
        to      : transaction._parent._address,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account.address}),
        gasPrice: await web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
        value   : value
    };
    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, account.privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    return receipt;
}

async function run() {
    const web3     = new Web3("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/" + PROJECT_ID);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDR);
    const account  = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(PRIVATE_KEY);
    const receipt  = await send(web3, account, contract.methods.registerUser("myName"));
    console.log(receipt);
}

run();
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to access PRIVATE_KEY and signTransaction on server side i.e. in NodeJS code?

Comment: @surhud004: Maybe not, but that (security aspect) was not a part of my investigation here (nor a part of your question, so you may want to post it as a separate one).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using your contract from the backend. In that case you cannot use MetaMask because it runs in the browser.

You have these options:

- Execute the transactions that make changes from the frontend. The UI has to connect to MetaMask and use it as provider for @truffle/contract.
- Use your own wallet in the backend and configure truffle to use it as provider. For example you can use [HDWallet Provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/hdwallet-provider#readme).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I will be considering the first option. Also, `Metamask` does not ask for confirming the transactions as well. I will have to resolve that problem too. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @surhud004 Follow MetaMask recommendations and it should work https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#basic-considerations. Make sure the code runs in the browser, if you don't get any request perhaps it is running in the backend server.