# How to sign transactions using Metamask and send the signed transaction to NodeJS so that it can be added on Ropsten Infura?

Tags: truffle, metamask, nodejs, infura

I have developed a secure file sharing application in **NodeJS**(v10.16.1) + **Express**(v4.17.1) + **Truffle**(v5.1.15) + **Metamask**(v7.7.8) which works perfectly on localhost. I am using **@truffle/contract**(v4.1.11) and interacting with the smart contract functions in NodeJS routes which then renders the front-end with the results. The NodeJS performs encryption, stores the file on **IPFS**(Infura API) and writes the returned hash to the smart contract.

Now, I want to integrate it with **Ropsten**(Infura API). However, Infura does not provide any method for [signing transactions](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_sendRawTransaction). It only has the `eth_sendRawTransaction` method which does not match with [truffle's](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract#sending-ether--triggering-the-fallback-function) `sendTransaction()`.

How can I sign the transaction using Metamask and then send it to NodeJS so as to add it on Infura's Ropsten Network?

One option is asking the user to enter `PRIVATE_KEY` from Metamask and sending it with the request. However, it is not a good option because of security issues.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Web3 does (provide a method for signing transactions). It's called `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction`, and you can see how to use it by reading [my answer to your previous question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/80625/16043) (or perhaps by reading it again, but more carefully this time). You can use this function on your client side (i.e., you don't have to send the private key to the server).

Comment: Why are you calling eth_sendRawTransaction from the backend? Executing sendTransaction from MetaMask is simpler. It will take care of signing and sending the message, you don't have to deal with nonces are any other user detail.

Comment: @goodvibration so can I signTransaction on client side and then send it as a POST request to NodeJS?

Comment: @Ismael because client uploads the file which goes to the server. The server then encrypts the file, uploads to IPFS and writes the returned hash value to smart contract thus, the sendTransaction from the backend.

Comment: What exactly does "send it as a POST request to NodeJS" mean? HTTP post requests are typically sent to an HTTP server.

Comment: @goodvibration Yes, the POST request in Express.

Comment: @surhud004: I don't know much about this technology, but it doesn't sound to me like it has anything related to Ethereum in any manner, so you might want to post that question on stack overflow or something similar.

Comment: @goodvibration Sure, thanks a lot for your help for this question as well as previous question :)

Comment: @surhud004: You're welcome :) Don't forget to accept that other one if it answers your question.

Comment: @surhud004 You can return the hash of the encrypted file to the frontend so the user will make the transaction. The other options is for the server to have its own private key to sign and send transactions.

Comment: @Ismael Sure, I will try that too. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!!